# Implementation of sequence of binary random variables in r

Tags: r, random-variable, binary-data

I am trying to implement a random variable in R, and I want to generate a sample from it.
The random variable looks like this: we have $P(X_{n}(\omega)=\frac{n}{n+1})=0.5$ and $P(X_{n}(\omega)=(-1)^{n})=0.5$ for a sequence $X_{1}, X_{2},...$of random variables which are independent. Can I inplement it in r as a binominal? If so, how? Would $rbinom(n=n, size=1, prob= 0.5* (1/(1:n))+0.5*(-1)^{n})$ be a proper solution?

Answer (score 2):

The way you code it just modifies the probabilities, not the outcomes.

If I understand your aim correctly, you rather want something like this:

```
N <- 20
n <- 1:N
x <- rbinom(n=N,size=1,prob=0.5) 
y <- (x==0)*n/(n+1)+(x==1)*(-1)^n
```

This first generates `N` 0s or 1s, and if element $n$ of the sequence is 0, it transforms to $n/(n+1)$ and to $(-1)^n$ else.